# Fetching data with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having a hard time to wrap my head around the best way to fetch data from an API only once (and when it's first requested) and then storing the result for reuse and/or other component functions. Below is a working example with `useContext` and `useReducer`, but it's quite complex for such an "easy" task.

Is there a better approach? And what's the best way to implement this for a large amount of API calls. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
  items: [],
  itemsLoading: false
};

const actions = {
  FETCHING_ITEMS: "FETCHING_ITEMS",
  FETCHED_ITEMS: "FETCHED_ITEMS"
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.FETCHING_ITEMS:
      return { ...state, itemsLoading: true, items: {} };

    case actions.FETCHED_ITEMS:
      return { ...state, items: action.value };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const Context = React.createContext();

const Provider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  const value = {
    items: state.items,
    itemsLoading: state.itemsLoading,
    fetchItems: () => {
      if (!state.itemsLoading) {
        dispatch({ type: actions.FETCHING_ITEMS });
        axios
          .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
          .then(function(response) {
            dispatch({ type: actions.FETCHED_ITEMS, value: response.data });
          });
      }
    }
  };

  return <Context.Provider value={value}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
};

const Filters = () => {
  const { items, fetchItems } = React.useContext(Context);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, [fetchItems]);

  const listItems = items.length
    ? items.map(item => {
        return <li key={item.id}>{item.title}</li>;
      })
    : "";

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
      <Filters />
    </Provider>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Can't get the snippet to work on SO, here is a working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-frog-4pdm1

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you consider this complex?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I struggle to imagine this approach to a real world application where there are multiple resources that need to be loaded and "cached" (for the lack of a better word) for future reuses. Should I keep all data in a single Context and combine multiple reducers for different actions.

Comment: You can implement multiple contexts to use multiple reducer or implement a single context to combine multiple reducers. The second approach is similar to a redux like solution

Comment: [React query](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query) handles multiple resources and caching.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you could write some abstraction around this using [custom hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) -

```js
const identity = x => x

const useAsync = (runAsync = identity, deps = []) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [error, setError] = useState(null)
  const [result, setResult] = useState(null)

  useEffect(_ => {
    Promise.resolve(runAsync(...deps))
      .then(setResult, setError)
      .finally(_ => setLoading(false))
  }, deps)

  return { loading, error, result }
}
```

You're excited so you start using it right away -

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { loading, error, result:items } =
    useAsync(_ => {
      axios.get("path/to/json")
        .then(res => res.json())
    }, ...)

  // ...
}
```

But stop there. Write more useful hooks when you need them -

```
const fetchJson = (url) =>
  axios.get(url).then(r => r.json())

const useJson = (url) =>
  useAsync(fetchJson, [url])

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { loading, error, result:items } =
    useJson("path/to/json")

  if (loading)
    return <p>Loading...</p>

  if (error)
    return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>

  return <div><Items items={items} /></div>
}
```

Conveniently [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) will only re-run the effect when the dependencies change. However if you expect to have expensive queries that you wish to handle with finer control, look at [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).