# How can I resolve this silly mistake in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-component, react-chartjs

I am completely new to react.js. This is a first project on react and I am just following the YouTube tutorials to create a covid-19 tracker application. I have build many components. I have to display a chart for that I have created `chart.jsx` file.

I am getting an unexpected error and I cannot resolve it but the tutor does not get that error in tutorial. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I am leaving the code below.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=khJlrj3Y6Ls&t=2279s At **45:35**

you can see it in tutorial at 45:35

This is the error I am getting and I know I am just making a silly mistake but I am not getting it.
[image]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { fetchDailyData } from '../../api';
import { Line, Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';

import styles from './Chart.module.css';

const Chart =() => {
    const [dailyData, setDailyData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
            setdailyData(await fetchDailyData());
        }

        fetchAPI();
    });

const lineChart = (
    dailyData.length
        ?(
    <Line 
        data={{
            labels: dailyData.map(({ date })=>date),
            datasets: [{
                data: dailyData.map(({ confirmed })=>confirmed),
                label:'Infected',
                borderColor: '#3333ff',
                fill:true,

            },{
                data: dailyData.map(({ deaths })=>deaths),
                label:'Infected',
                borderColor: 'red',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
                fill:true,
            }],
        }}
    />):null
);
    return(
        <div className={styles.container}>
            {lineChart}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chart;
```

Comment: `setdailyData(await fetchDailyData());` should be `setDailyData(await fetchDailyData());`

Comment: @Fazil, I hope you read [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61782848/633183) and find it helpful

Comment: Are you sure that you want to callthis effect and fetch data on **every** render? [check out dependencies](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `>` here:

```
const fetchAPI = async () = {
```

It should be:

```
const fetchAPI = async () => {
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I am getting this error now can you please help?

./src/components/Chart/Chart.jsx
  Line 12:13:  'setdailyData' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: See the comment by Denis Tsoi on your question