# How can I get data from AsyncStorage and add it to initial state when using useReducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, react-hooks, asyncstorage

I'm using **useContext** & **useReducer** from Hooks & **AsyncStorage.setItem** in **useEffect** to save the data whenever state gets updated. On app reload I want to make sure to get saved data using **AsyncStorage.getItem** and add it to the initial state.

I tried to add init function with async as the third property to useReducer but still, it's not replacing initial data with received data. Please go through below code and help.

Thank you in advance!

Current code where I can save data to AsyncStorage

```
  const [user, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, {});

  useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
  }, [user]);

  return(
    <UserContext.Provider value={{user,dispatch}}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Below is the code I tried, but unable save existing data as initial data.

```
const getUser = async function() {
  const userData = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
  console.log("parse");
  console.log(userData);
  console.log("parsed data");
  console.log(JSON.parse(userData));
  return userData ? JSON.parse(userData) : {};
}

export const UserContext = createContext();

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [user, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, {}, getUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("context");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
  }, [user]);

  return(
    <UserContext.Provider value={{user,dispatch}}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think you will find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61778948) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you!
Updated and working code based on below suggestion and with minor changes.

```
const getUser = async () => {
  try {
    const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
    return user ? JSON.parse(user) : {};
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to fetch the data from storage');
  }
}
export const UserContext = createContext();

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [user, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, {});

  // Loading initial Satte
  useEffect(() => {
     async function fetchUser() {
       const user = await getUser();
       dispatch({type: 'ADD_USER', user});
     }
     fetchUser();
  }, []);

  // Update AsyncStorage when user is updated
  useEffect(() => {
    // This check is required to avoid initial writing to asyncStorage
    if(user) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
    }
  }, [user]);


  return(
    <UserContext.Provider value={{user,dispatch}}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I have been going round in circles for days, this final gave me what i needed

Answer (score 1):

Your **initial state to useReducer needs to synchronous**. Since asyncStorage is not a synchronous API you can't actually pass the value as initialState

You however can make use of `useEffect loading state` like below

```
const getUser = async () => {
   try {
       const user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')
       return user ? JSON.parse(user) : {};
   } catch (e) {
       console.log('Failed to fetch the data from storage');
   }
}

export const UserContext = createContext();

const UserContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, dispatch] = useReducer(userReducer, {});

  // Loading initial Satte
  useEffect(() => {
     async function fetchUser() {
         const user = await getUser();
         setIsLoading(false);
         dispatch({type: 'INIT_REDUCER', user}); // You must handle initReducer in reducer
     }
     fetchUser();
 }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(user) {
        // This check is required to avoid initial writing to asyncStorage
        console.log("context");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
        AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
    }
  }, [user]);

  if(isLoading) {
     return (
       <View> 
           <Text>Loading...</Text> 
       </View>
     );
  }
  return(
    <UserContext.Provider value={{user,dispatch}}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```